# Skinr classes on <body> tag

Tags: 7, theming

I would like to use page level skins in my theme, for example.

If I make Colors widget for my skin where I can choose Red/Green/Blue colors and I choose Blue, the class blue is added to body tag.

As far as I know, I've set up Skiner properly, the above is working for regions, blocks etc, but when I set it for page, the class is not showing anywhere.

I appriciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in the meantime.

In fact, there wasn't even a problem. I was adjusting the skins for the node, when I tought I'm doing that for the whole page. What I didn't notice at the time is that there is a contextual link icon in the top righ corner, and you have to use that in order to adjust the skin for the whole page.